# Google Analytics authorization in java

Tags: java, google-analytics, authorization

I'm looking for the simplest way of programmatically logging in into Analytics and get data. Google documentation writes and gives examples for Oauth 2.0 which involves a user manually logging into with his google account, and then being redirected to my site with authorization. But this is not what I want to achieve - I'm building an automatic tool that needs to have user/pass or any other authorization key to be hard-coded and then log in without any user involvement (this is a periodic reporting tool).

I already found something about API KEY, but I can't find any example how to do that, or how to to that with Google java libraries.

I would be very grateful for pointing me into right direction. Also this may be valuable clue for others how to do it the simplest way - and I think logging should be simple.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and I took me about 1h to find this in the v3 documentation:

> Service Accounts
>
> Useful for automated/offline/scheduled access to Google Analytics data for your own account. For example, to build a live dashboard of your own Google Analytics data and share it with other users.
>
> There are a few steps you need to follow to configure service accounts to work with Google Analytics:
>
> 1. Register a project in the APIs Console.
> 2. In the Google APIs Console, under the API Access pane, create a client ID with the Application Type set to Service Account.
> 3. Sign-in to Google Analytics and navigate to the Admin section.
> 4. Select the account for which you want the application to have access to.
> 5. Add the email address, from the Client ID created in the APIs Console from step #2, as a user of the selected Google Analytics account.
> 6. Follow the instructions for Service Accounts to access Google Analytics data.

Read more here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataAuthorization

Puh, I guess the API is so big Google is having trouble documenting it an easy way =)

Then I looked at the code in the **plus-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample** and **analytics-cmdline-sample**. This is a very basic version implemented in a Playframework2 java app that
prints to System.out as the examples above:

```
private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

public static Result index() {
   GoogleCredential credential = null;
   try {
        credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
              .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
              .setServiceAccountId("2363XXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
              .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY))
              .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("/your/path/to/privatekey/privatekey.p12"))                          
              .build();
     } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();  
     }

     // Set up and return Google Analytics API client.
     Analytics analytics = new Analytics.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
          "Google-Analytics-Hello-Analytics-API-Sample").build();

     String profileId = "";
     try {
         profileId = getFirstProfileId(analytics);
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
     }

     GaData gaData = null;
     try {
        gaData = executeDataQuery(analytics, profileId);
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     printGaData(gaData);

     return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
}

private static String getFirstProfileId(Analytics analytics) throws IOException {
    String profileId = null;

    // Query accounts collection.
    Accounts accounts = analytics.management().accounts().list().execute();

    if (accounts.getItems().isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("No accounts found");
    } else {
        String firstAccountId = accounts.getItems().get(0).getId();

        // Query webproperties collection.
        Webproperties webproperties =
                analytics.management().webproperties().list(firstAccountId).execute();

        if (webproperties.getItems().isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("No Webproperties found");
        } else {
            String firstWebpropertyId = webproperties.getItems().get(0).getId();

            // Query profiles collection.
            Profiles profiles =
                    analytics.management().profiles().list(firstAccountId, firstWebpropertyId).execute();

            if (profiles.getItems().isEmpty()) {
                System.err.println("No profiles found");
            } else {
                profileId = profiles.getItems().get(0).getId();
            }
        }
    }
    return profileId;
}

/**
 * Returns the top 25 organic search keywords and traffic source by visits. The Core Reporting API
 * is used to retrieve this data.
 *
 * @param analytics the analytics service object used to access the API.
 * @param profileId the profile ID from which to retrieve data.
 * @return the response from the API.
 * @throws IOException tf an API error occured.
 */
private static GaData executeDataQuery(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
    return analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileId, // Table Id. ga: + profile id.
            "2012-01-01", // Start date.
            "2012-01-14", // End date.
            "ga:visits") // Metrics.
            .setDimensions("ga:source,ga:keyword")
            .setSort("-ga:visits,ga:source")
            .setFilters("ga:medium==organic")
            .setMaxResults(25)
            .execute();
}

/**
 * Prints the output from the Core Reporting API. The profile name is printed along with each
 * column name and all the data in the rows.
 *
 * @param results data returned from the Core Reporting API.
 */
private static void printGaData(GaData results) {
    System.out.println("printing results for profile: " + results.getProfileInfo().getProfileName());

    if (results.getRows() == null || results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No results Found.");
    } else {

        // Print column headers.
        for (GaData.ColumnHeaders header : results.getColumnHeaders()) {
            System.out.printf("%30s", header.getName());
        }
        System.out.println();

        // Print actual data.
        for (List<String> row : results.getRows()) {
            for (String column : row) {
                System.out.printf("%30s", column);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does this in fact work? In particular, the P12 file: do you create it or is it downloaded. Also, is a new API key needed for each machine upon which this code is to run?

Comment: When creating the service account, don't select the preferred (by Google) JSON, but select P12. I spend some time looking for how to create a `PrivateKey` from a JSON file, but could not find anything within a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it finally with the 2.4 version of Core Reporting - there's autorization with your gmail user/pass, just as simple as it should be - I wonder why there's no example how to do this in new 3.0 version.

Core reporting 2.4: http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v2/gdataJava.html

Comment: Your post really helps me. The 3.0 version document is so confusing and useless. It misses a lot of important steps such as how to compile client_secrets.json and points to such 'what!!?' links.

Again, Thanks.

Comment: that page removed by google i am facing this issue from last 20 days can you share the code what exactly you are used to access google analytic data

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to follow the example provided and it does not compile. I don't know if this is 3.0 vs 2.4 and if so, is there a way that the example code can be made to work -- proper choice of jars or what.

One problem with the example is that the argument to setServiceAccountScopes is no longer a string but a Collections.singleton(AnalyticsScopes.Analytics.READ_ONLY).

Also important to using the example is proper configuration of the Service Account.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to another question I wrote a code example in Java which works for me.

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24043488/1391050