# OAuth 2.0 with Google Analytics API v3

Tags: oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, garb-gem

I used to be able to query the Google Analytics API with my account's login & password.
Google is now using OAuth for authentication which is great...
The only issue is that I only need ONE access token.
I don't wanna allow other users to fetch THEIR analytics data.

I just wanna be able to fetch MY data.
Is there a way I can generate an access token only for my app or my analytics account?

I know such solutions exists... For instance, Twitter provides what they call a "single-user oauth" for apps that don't require a specific user to sign in.

One again, all I'm trying to accomplish here is to fetch MY OWN analytics data via the API.

Is there a way to properly do that?

Answer (score 40):

I'm adding a PHP answer - you may be able to adjust or convert it to garb / ruby code.

You should be able to use Analytics with service accounts now. You will indeed have to use a private key instead of an access token.

**Create an app in the API Console**
Basically, you go to the Google API Console and create an App.
Enable Google Analytics in the services tab.
In the API Access tab, create a new OAuth ID (Create another client ID... button), select **service account** and download your private key (Generate new key... link). You'll have to upload the key to your web server later.

On the API Access page, in the Service account section, copy the email address (@developer.gserviceaccount.com) and add a new user with this email address to your Google Analytics profile. **If you do not do this, you'll get some nice errors**

**Code**
Download the latest Google PHP Client off SVN (from the command line `svn checkout http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-php-client-read-only`).

You can now access the Analytics API in code:

```
require_once 'Google_Client.php';              
require_once 'contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';

$keyfile = 'dsdfdss0sdfsdsdfsdf44923dfs9023-privatekey.p12';

// Initialise the Google Client object
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Your product name');

$client->setAssertionCredentials(
    new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        '11122233344@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
        file_get_contents($keyfile)
    )
);

// Get this from the Google Console, API Access page
$client->setClientId('11122233344.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setAccessType('offline_access');
$analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

// We have finished setting up the connection,
// now get some data and output the number of visits this week.

// Your analytics profile id. (Admin -> Profile Settings -> Profile ID)
$analytics_id   = 'ga:1234';
$lastWeek       = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
$today          = date('Y-m-d');

try {
    $results = $analytics->data_ga->get($analytics_id,
                        $lastWeek,
                        $today,'ga:visits');
    echo '<b>Number of visits this week:</b> ';
    echo $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visits'];
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I knew there had to be a way to do this, but couldn't find the correct details in the API docs. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried this and no success. This is the link to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465689/service-applications-and-google-analytics-api-v3-error-101-neterr-connection

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I had already pulled half of my hair out trying to authenticate a service app, but this answer saved the other half.

Comment: Hmm.. I followed this to a T, and I get `There was an error : - Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'
`.

Comment: Odd... I deleted my project and re-created a new one... The service email and client-id looked WAY different... and it works now... How odd... But oh well, it works now!!

Comment: (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#q=visit&cats=visitor,session)

Answer (score 7):

[Terry Seidler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12892625/1391050) answered this nicely for php. I want to add a **java** code example.

### Api console setup

Start by doing the required steps in the google api console as Terry explained:

> Basically, you go to the Google API Console and create an App. Enable
>   Google Analytics in the services tab. In the API Access tab, create a
>   new OAuth ID (Create another client ID... button), select service
>   account and download your private key (Generate new key... link).
>   You'll have to upload the key to your web server later.
>   On the API Access page, in the Service account section, copy the email
>   address (@developer.gserviceaccount.com) and add a new user with this
>   email address to your Google Analytics profile. If you do not do this,
>   you'll get some nice errors

### Get the necessary libraries

Download the google analytics java client from:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/analytics/v3

Or add the following maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-analytics</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev94-1.18.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.0-rc</version>
    </dependency>
```

### Now for the code:

```
public class HellowAnalyticsV3Api {

private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

public void analyticsExample() {

    // This is the .p12 file you got from the google api console by clicking generate new key
    File analyticsKeyFile = new File(<p12FilePath>);

    // This is the service account email address that you can find in the api console
    String apiEmail = <something@developer.gserviceaccount.com>;

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(apiEmail)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY))
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(analyticsPrivateKeyFile).build();

    Analytics analyticsService = new Analytics.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(<your application name>)
        .build();


    String startDate = "2014-01-03";
    String endDate = "2014-03-03";
    String mertrics = "ga:sessions,ga:timeOnPage";

    // Use the analytics object build a query
    Get get = analyticsService.data().ga().get(tableId, startDate, endDate, mertrics);
    get.setDimensions("ga:city");
    get.setFilters("ga:country==Canada");
    get.setSort("-ga:sessions");

    // Run the query
    GaData data = get.execute();

    // Do something with the data
    if (data.getRows() != null) {
        for (List<String> row : data.getRows()) {
            System.out.println(row);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a refresh token. Store the refresh token in a db or secure config file, then use it to show the stats.

[Google API Offline Access Using OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token](http://www.jensbits.com/2012/01/09/google-api-offline-access-using-oauth-2-0-refresh-token/) will give you an idea of how to capture then store your refresh token.

See also [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications - Offline Access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline)

Answer (score 1):

Hello I found a solution, it works for me

you have to change this one

```
immediate: true
```

to

```
immediate: false
```

and it looks like

```
function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google has the 'Service Account' (Calls Google APIs on behalf of your application instead of an end-user), but the way it works is a bit different as it won't use access tokens but a private key instead.

You can find more details at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: This won't work. Service accounts currently can't access data that is "user data" of which analytics seems to apply. go with the oauth2 method.