# Get google analytics API data without requiring login

Tags: oauth, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OAuth 2.0 with Google Analytics API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057928/oauth-2-0-with-google-analytics-api-v3)

I've been reading loads of pages about the Google API today and how it requires Oauth2.0

The documentation on Google's own site is useless and keeps sending you round in circles so I'm hoping somebody here might be able to help.

I'm trying to build a simple test webpage (on http ://localhost) which takes data from the Analytics API, always from the same account.

So, I have an API key and would like to get data from this 1 account without requiring users of my site to login (they wouldn't be able to do that anyway, it's my account).

So, is there a way to authenticate my app on localhost programatically via HTTP or something. It seems like I shouldn't need to use Oauth unless my users were accessing their own accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is only possible if you get some user to log in first and use a "refresh token", as per the link posted by Jan above