# PHP openssl_sign stops executing any and all scripting

Tags: php, openssl

I'm having trouble with openssl. To better pinpoint the problem I've done two things; I reduced the code to a single test page (which I've gotten off of php.net). And after the problem persisted I uploaded tat code to a server. The server worked as expected, so the problem must be in my setup!? I found someone who experienced the exact same problem, but his code was different and the solution doesn't work for me ([Service Applications and Google Analytics API V3: Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465689/service-applications-and-google-analytics-api-v3-error-101-neterr-connection)).

This is the code:

```
<?php

$data = "Beeeeer is really good.. hic...";

// You can get a simple private/public key pair using:
// openssl genrsa 512 >private_key.txt
// openssl rsa -pubout <private_key.txt >public_key.txt

// IMPORTANT: The key pair below is provided for testing only.
// For security reasons you must get a new key pair
// for production use, obviously.

$private_key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOgIBAAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4Z
RZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQJAL151ZeMKHEU2c1qdRKS9
sTxCcc2pVwoAGVzRccNX16tfmCf8FjxuM3WmLdsPxYoHrwb1LFNxiNk1MXrxjH3R
6QIhAPB7edmcjH4bhMaJBztcbNE1VRCEi/bisAwiPPMq9/2nAiEA3lyc5+f6DEIJ
h1y6BWkdVULDSM+jpi1XiV/DevxuijMCIQCAEPGqHsF+4v7Jj+3HAgh9PU6otj2n
Y79nJtCYmvhoHwIgNDePaS4inApN7omp7WdXyhPZhBmulnGDYvEoGJN66d0CIHra
I2SvDkQ5CmrzkW5qPaE2oO7BSqAhRZxiYpZFb5CI
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;
$public_key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6
zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4ZRZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOD;

$binary_signature = "";

// At least with PHP 5.2.2 / OpenSSL 0.9.8b (Fedora 7)
// there seems to be no need to call openssl_get_privatekey or similar.
// Just pass the key as defined above

openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $private_key, "sha1");

// Check signature
$ok = openssl_verify($data, $binary_signature, $public_key, "sha1");
echo "check #1: ";
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "signature ok (as it should be)\n";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad (there's something wrong)\n";
} else {
    echo "ugly, error checking signature\n";
}

$ok = openssl_verify('tampered'.$data, $binary_signature, $public_key, "sha1");
echo "check #2: ";
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "ERROR: Data has been tampered, but signature is still valid! Argh!\n";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad signature (as it should be, since data has beent tampered)\n";
} else {
    echo "ugly, error checking signature\n";
}
```

When I run the code above the page takes a while to load, but then displays net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET:

[image: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET]

I have openssl enabled
[image: openssl]

And I am using PHP 5.4.7
[image: PHP 5.4.7]

These are just as the other case I found, except I'm not initiating anything twice, and this code works on the server, which is PHP 5.3.18.

What more can I do?

Comment: Honestly, I'd just use phpseclib to accomplish this task. The openssl extension is finicky and, dare I say, unreliable. Here's an example of how to do this with phpseclib: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html#sign,sign2

Comment: It looks like one problem is that your version of PHP is messed up, it is using 1 version for OpenSSL headers, and other for OpenSSL lib files.  You should recompile php and get the version numbers to line up.  Then see if you still have the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

velcrow seems to be right. I've reinstalled and now all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is in due to different versions of OpenSSL Library and OpenSSL Header.

Try PHP version >= 5.5 . You will not face this issue.

**Note:** *If you are using XAMP all the version 1.8.* are having this issues avoid using them
in case you want to use OpenSSL.*

Comment: My question originated before PHP 5.5 was even released. It is also almost 6 years old and I haven't seen the issue again..