# Retrieving google analytics data without login

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a dashboard which uses google analytics data of my site to show required charts. The problem with it is, it requires user login every time i wish to view the data. Is there any way i can do this without the need to login ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OAuth 2.0 with Google Analytics API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057928/oauth-2-0-with-google-analytics-api-v3)

Comment: Depends on language the dashboard is programed in.  But if its your own data you could look into a Service account.  Then you will never have to log in.