# How do I create a Google Spreadsheet with a service account and share to other google users in java?

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have an application where I, with a **Google Service Account**, gather lots of information about my site from the Analytics API. 
My next step is to create a spreadsheet with the service account
and share the document with a couple of users.

I have checked out the documentation at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ but I can't find anything there about service accounts and sharing the documents.

So my first question is this possible? 
If not do I need to implement the "use my personal account" as exemplified in the documentation?
If yes could you please provide me with an example?

Thank you!

Comment: any final solution did you tried ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible, see the example below (the example does need a bit of tweaking):

Create the drive service:

```
   GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(confBean.getServiceAccountId()).setServiceAccountScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("path to the P12File"))
            .setServiceAccountUser("user@domain.com")
            .build();

    Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
```

Create the spreadsheet:

```
  com.google.api.services.drive.model.File  file = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
  file.setTitle("test");       
  file.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  Insert insert = this.drive.files().insert(file);
  file = insert.execute();
```

Create a spreadsheet service:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(confBean.getServiceAccountId()).setServiceAccountScopes("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds")
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("path to the P12File"))
        .setServiceAccountUser("user@domain.com")
        .build();
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

Retrieve the sheet:

```
SpreadsheetService s = googleConn.getSpreadSheetService();
String spreadsheetURL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/" + file.getId();
SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = s.getEntry(new URL(spreadsheetURL), SpreadsheetEntry.class);
```

Add the data:

```
WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = s.getFeed(spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);

URL cellFeedUrl= worksheet.getCellFeedUrl ();
CellFeed cellFeed= s.getFeed (cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);

CellEntry cellEntry= new CellEntry (1, 1, "aa");
cellFeed.insert (cellEntry);
```

Also, see this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253955/invalid-grant-when-calling-java-google-drive-api-with-service-account/13259738)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have encountered some issues with the impl. When doing setServiceAccountUser("user@domain.com") I get a TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request "error" : "access_denied" back from the API. If I remove the setServiceAccountUser part i get a 500 Internal server error. I have enabled Google Drive API and Google Drive SDK in the Google services console. What am I missing here? There is no problem with the analytics as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084840/google-analytics-authorization-in-java/12892390#12892390

Comment: Make sure you enable both the drive and docs api in the api console, and authorize the application for: https://docs.google.com/feeds 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive. And I assume you changed the user@domain.com to a real user in the domain?

Comment: Hmm It seems to me that I I'm missing some crucial part here.

Comment: Now I'm getting com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request { "error" : "invalid_grant"}. I'm using the the same client id as I did for analytics:2363681XX719.apps.googleusercontent.com and the user@domain.com I have tried with 2363681XX719@developer.gserviceaccount.com and an email that is registered at my domain. Maybe that is the problem how do I check if the user is correct at my domain? Do I need anything more? Maybe I have forgot something?

Comment: There are two sections in the code, creating the spreadsheet and manipulating it. Where do you get the error?

Comment: The creating part on: The file = insert.execute();

Comment: Make sure both the drive and the docs api are enabled in the API Console. And https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive is granted access in the "Manage API client access"

Comment: Hmmm I can't find docs in my console, isn't docs included in the drive api? In my Manage API client access have have tried with 2363681XX719.apps.googleusercontent.com for scopes https://www.docs.google.com/feeds https://www.spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19152/discussion-between-jasper-duizendstra-and-jakob)