# Google Sheets API: Setting permissions

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Within my Java application I am creating new Google sheets as follows:

```
    Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();

    SpreadsheetProperties properties = new SpreadsheetProperties();
    properties.setTitle("Title");

    Spreadsheet export = new Spreadsheet();
    export.setProperties(properties);

    Spreadsheet response = service.spreadsheets().create(export).execute();
```

This works, and I can get the sheet ID in the response. Now I would like to know:

1. As I am using Service account, I don't see who will be the user creating the spreadsheet.
2. I would like to set permissions to "Anyone who has the link", but there seem to be no option for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As I am using Service account, I don't see who will be the user creating the spreadsheet.**

You can make use of "user" as type like:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId(confBean.getServiceAccountId()).setServiceAccountScopes("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds")
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("path to the P12File"))
        .setServiceAccountUser("user@domain.com")
        .build();
```

But it really depends on your end goal. Here are the possible [Types and Values](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing).

***user*** - *emailAddress* - Email address of a user. Example: joe@thecompany.com

**group** - *emailAddress* -  Email address of a Google Group. Example: admins@thecompany.com domain-

***domain*** - Domain name of Google Apps domain. Example: thecompany.com anyone - N/A The

***anyone*** - permission does not require an emailAddress or domain field.

Check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229294/how-do-i-create-a-google-spreadsheet-with-a-service-account-and-share-to-other-g) for addtional info.

**I would like to set permissions to "Anyone who has the link", but there seem to be no option for that.**

Use "anyone" as user type which has been mentioned above. Then use "reader" as role.

```
private Permission insertPermission(Drive service, String fileId) throws Exception{
   Permission newPermission = new Permission();
   newPermission.setType("anyone");
   newPermission.setRole("reader");
   newPermission.setValue("");
   newPermission.setWithLink(true);
   return service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).execute();
}
```

Check this helpful [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155441/set-file-sharing-level-to-anyone-with-the-link-through-google-drive-api).