# How to restrict specific google user can read/write the google sheet?

Tags: php, google-sheets, permissions, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet, I follow the step of PHP Quickstart (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) to code the PHP script to read/write a Google sheet. I don't know how to manage the read/write permission.

Here is the code of the PHP script

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('SurveyApp');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
$spreadsheetId = '<my sheet id>';
$options = array('valueInputOption' => 'RAW');
$updateRange = "FormRange!F1:F3";
$requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
$requestBody->setValues([["Blue"],["Green"],["Red"]]);
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $updateRange, $requestBody, $options);
```

I have 3 Google accounts, e.g. GooA, GooB and GooC. There is a Google Sheet, User GooA is the owner of the sheet.

I deliberately don't share the sheet to anyone with the read/write access.  I try to delete the token.json from the server and rebuild it with account GooB login and paste the verification code.

I get Error 500 when I execute the PHP script by all users including the owner GooA. I share the sheet to user GooC with **can edit** permission, Error 500 is still exist until I share the sheet to GooB with **can edit** permission. I read the log and find the Error 500 is about the permission issue.

Once I share the sheet to the user GooB who generates the verification code with **can edit** permission, all users including anonymous (without login with Google account) can execute the PHP script without error.

In the PHP script, it has the code to write/get values to/from the sheet, how can I grant the specific user can execute the script?

Best regards,

Kelvin.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from this documentation on how to [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing). When your application requests private data, the request must be authorized by an authenticated user who has access to that data.

There are two ways to identify your application:

- using an [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#AboutAuthorization) token (which also authorizes the request)
- and/or using the application's [API key](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey). Here's how to determine which of those options to use:

Here's also another way to set the type of permission to users, check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434401/google-sheets-api-setting-permissions) for more details.